# Executing SQL commands through custom plugin

Tags: postgresql, plugins, grafana, grafana-api

I am developing a plugin to get familar with the platform and make some proof of concepts. I am trying to execute SQL commands to a local postgres database directly in my plugin through a button component.

Currently I am trying to run the command using, getDataSourceSrv to grab the user defined datasource from Grafana. Then I am using the query() to try and execute the command. Within this query I am setting my target as my query which is a SQL command. I have established that I am connecting to my database however I either receieve a Bad Request or dont seem to recieve any response.

Here is an example of my current implementation.

```
const datasource = await getDataSourceSrv().get('PostgreSQL')
      console.log(datasource)
        const response = await datasource.query({ 
        requestId: 'A',
        interval: '30s',
        intervalMs: 30000,
        maxDataPoints: 1000,
        range: {
          from: dateTime().subtract(1, 'h'),
          to: dateTime(),
          raw: {
            from: 'now-1h',
            to: 'now',
          },
        },
        scopedVars: {},
        targets: [query],
        timezone: 'browser',
        app: 'dashboard',
        startTime: Date.now()
        })
```

where query is

```
const query = "SELECT * FROM placeholder"
```

Comment: A plugin in which software?

Comment: In Grafana version 10